# VBA check for alert on web page in a <li> </li> and run Sub if detected

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to compare the sting in `li` This one is probably super easy and I tried to do the same thing i did with cycling through the Href's on a table the site generates but it doesn't work the same.

```
<div class="text" id="vs" style="left: 908px; top: 97px; width: 391px; color: red; position: absolute; z-index: 251;">
    <ul><li>Has Duplicated Billed Line Item(s).</li></ul>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far but the red var doesn't populate

```
Set allalert = appIE.document.getElementById("vs").getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each alert In allalert
If alert = "Has Duplicated Billed Line Item(s)." Then
 Call Dupe_Bill_process
Next alert
```

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks to everyone that's been helping me through this learning process I've actually getting OK at this stuff lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare against the `.innerText` property as you are comparing against an object at present. You can also drop the obselete `call` key word.

```
Set allalert = appIE.document.getElementById("vs").getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each alert In allalert
If alert.innerText = "Has Duplicated Billed Line Item(s)." Then
    Dupe_Bill_process
    'Exit For ''?
Next alert
```

You may want an `Exit For` if you want to exit immediately after first match. Or simply use `appIE.document.getElementById("vs").getElementsByTagName("li")(0)`

---

I would also consider simply collecting a nodeList using css selectors. As you are using an actual browser this should be faster.

```
#vs > ul
```

That is:

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("#vs > ul")
For i = 0 to nodeList.Length-1
    If nodeList.item(i).innerText = "Has Duplicated Billed Line Item(s)." Then
        Dupe_Bill_process
    End If
Next
```

---

If you only care about the first matched the code simply becomes:

```
If ie.document.querySelector("#vs > ul").innerText = "Has Duplicated Billed Line Item(s)." Then
    Dupe_Bill_process
End If
```

Comment: Dude the nodelist was a great idea too, Thanks for the help again. I'm obviously still learning but the help you gave me today and yesterday has made a very tedious part of my job way more bearable.

Comment: No worries.  Any other questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reference the innerText of the elements you're trying to validate.

```
If alert.innerText = "Has Duplicated Billed Line Item(s)." Then
    Call Dupe_Bill_process
Next alert
```